# How the terms are arranged in `CoefficientList` command?

Tags: expression-manipulation, coefficients

I have an expression containing various orders (powers) of `F[r]`. Using `CoefficientList`, the output is a blue box which is because of the complicated form of it. 
[image]
For example, I have used:

```
CC = CoefficientList[expression, F[r]]
```

Now, how to pick each certain answer in it? I mean, for example, if I pick one of them with

```
CC[[1]]
```

which power of `F[r]` is it?

In other words, how can I know how many answers there are in `CC` and each one is related to which order?

Comment: `CC` containes coefficients of  $F(r)^0, F(r)^1, F(r)^2,\ldots,F(r)^m$  where `m` is the largest exponent of $F(r)$ in `expression`.

Comment: @kglr How about the minus powers (if exist)? The problem is I don't know anything about the powers.

Comment: Perfect Fluid, `CoefficientList` works only for polynomials (that is, exponents have to be non-negative integers)

Comment: If `CC = CoefficientList[expression, F[r]]` returns a list without an error message then `expression` is a polynomial in `F[r]` and `Exponent[expression, F[r]]` gives the maximum power with which `F[r]` appears in `expression` (and the length of `CC` is `1+ Exponent[expression, F[r]]`.)

Comment: @kglr So you mean `CC[[3]]` is definitely the coefficient of $F[r]^2$?

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: Of course, you do not have to take kglr's word for it; you can easily verify it yourself: `Sum[CC[[k + 1]] F[r]^k, {k, 0, Length[CC] - 1}] == expression // Simplify`

Comment: @J.M.isaway I have chosen these stories because of the problem in `Simplify`ing the `expression`.

Comment: "...because of the problem in `Simplify`ing the `expression`..." - just to confirm, have you already seen `Collect[]`?

Comment: @J.M.isaway Yes. But `Collect[]` leads to a blue box too! The aim is to `Simplify` each term and finally simplify sum of them. In fact `expression` is very complicated.

Comment: "But `Collect[]` leads to a blue box too!" - ah, so you didn't use the *third* argument of `Collect[]`, then? `Collect[expression, F[r], Simplify]`

Comment: @J.M.isaway yessssssssssssssssssss. It is good. Thank you! I didn't know about this damn third argument :((

Comment: Yes, this is why you have to read the documentation carefully the next time. It's mentioned right in the usage message.

Comment: @J.M.isaway, Of course, you right. However, I needed this answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`CoefficientList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html):

> - CoefficientList[poly,var]
>     *gives a list of coefficients of powers of* var *in* poly, *starting with power 0*.

That is, `CoefficientList[poly, x]` gives coefficients of  $\{x^0, x^1, x^2, \ldots, x^m\}$ (in that order) where `m` is `Exponent[poly, x]` (the largest power with which `x` appears in `poly`.)

To take a simple example to illustrate:

```
ClearAll[x, y, a, b, c, d]
expr = 1 + a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + d y^3;

CCx = CoefficientList[expr, x]
```

> {1 + c y^2 + d y^3, b y, a}

```
Length[CCx] == 1 + Exponent[expr, x]
```

> True

```
CCy = CoefficientList[expr, y]
```

> {1 + a x^2, b x, c, d}

```
Length[CCy] == 1 + Exponent[expr, y]
```

> True

`k`th entry of `CCx` is the coefficient of `x^(k-1)`:

```
k = 2;
{CCx[[k]] , Coefficient[expr, x, k - 1]}
```

> {b y, b y}

```
{CCy[[k]] , Coefficient[expr, y, k - 1]}
```

> {b x, b x}

Per J.M.'s comment, to verify you can use

```
Sum[CCx[[k]] x^(k - 1), {k, 1, 1 + Exponent[expr, x]}] == expr
```

> True

```
Sum[CCy[[k]] y^(k - 1), {k, 1, 1 + Exponent[expr, y]}] == expr
```

> True

With multiple variables in the second argument, we get an array:

```
CCxy = CoefficientList[expr, {x, y}]
```

> {{1, 0, c, d}, {0, b, 0, 0}, {a, 0, 0, 0}}

`{i,j}`th entry of `CCxy` is the coefficient of $x^{i-1} y^{j-1}$.

A template to read this array:

```
template = Array[HoldForm[Power[x, #] Power[y, #2]] &,  1 + Exponent[expr, {x, y}], 0];

Row[MatrixForm /@ {CCxy, template}]
```

> $\Large \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 0 & c & d \\
>  0 & b & 0 & 0 \\
>  a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  x^0 y^0 & x^0 y^1 & x^0 y^2 & x^0 y^3 \\
>  x^1 y^0 & x^1 y^1 & x^1 y^2 & x^1 y^3 \\
>  x^2 y^0 & x^2 y^1 & x^2 y^2 & x^2 y^3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$